# Firing eventListener only once for all the instances of my constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have a shared property across all the instances of my constructor:

```
function Me() { }
Me.prototype.window = {};
```

I'd like to update it's content on `window` resize, but I'd like to do it only once for each resize event, no matter how many instances of my constructor have been created.

Logically, if I define the eventListener as below, in the initialization of my instances, it will be fired multiple times

```
function Me() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    this.window = window.outerWidth;
  }.bind(this));
}
var a = new Me();
var b = new Me();
// on resize, the callback is called twice
```

How can I do it?

Comment: downvoters please explain, the question is legit and it's properly exposed.

Comment: Show the full code of your constructor. The question is not fully clear and not fully documented.

Comment: We don't know what you do and don't have. Show us the constructor.

Comment: First, you don't post your code  in the comments, you go back and update the question. And, again if your question is about a constructor, you show the relevant code.

Comment: Because without ALL the code you have, we can't get the full picture of what you are doing and give you a good answer. You may not think it's important, but it is.

Comment: Now, what do you have for the code of the window.resize event callback code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do it?

Have a flag that indicates whether to bind the event handler or not. Then, in the constructor you only need to check the flag:

```
if (bindHandler) {
  // ... bind handler
  bindHandler = false;
}
```

How / where you store the flag is up to you.

Comment: I suggested that to him earlier and he said I was making all the classes useless and added bloat! Turns out in his own solution, he does the same thing, but with an array. I was going to suggest that to him, but though he'd find that too much code!

Comment: I'm sure you had my same idea, I'm really sure. Thanks all for the nice suggestions.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: At least we can move on with our lives now.

Comment: I didn't thought I was so important to you! Thanks <3

Answer (score -1):

Thought I'd put back all the answers I gave to show how OP has not provided all pertinent information up front. Also, the answer he finally came up with and marked correct was one I offered and he shot down.

---

First, I offered what is probably the most simple solution:

Put the following completely outside of the constructor function. When the window is resized, the shared property is updated - - for all instances.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  Me.prototype.window = window.outerWidth;
};
```

The OP then added new information that this would not be good because if no instances of `Me` existed, the callback would still be registered on the prototype.

---

I then offered this which interestingly, he marked as the answer when someone else posted it.

Your next solution would have to be to track whether there are any instances of `Me` before the event listener is registered. That would mean that you'd need to keep track of whether any instances exist:

```
// Global variabel to track if Me instances exist
var meInstances = false

var me1 = new Me();
meInstances = true;

if(meInstances){
   window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
     Me.prototype.window = window.outerWidth;
   };
}
```

But, when I posted it, the response was: "you are completely making useless all the classes, constructors and stuff like that logic. There's not isolation, you are adding a lot of code for nothing and the solution is not robust." In fact, the OP then came up with his own solution that uses an array to store the instances and then the length of the array can be checked to see if there are any. I was actually going to suggest that, but went with the Boolean flag because the OP kept saying he wanted simple.

---

So, I offered this:

What about:

```
function Me() {
  // This code only runs when instance is being made

  // This instance is registers a callback
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {

    // Callback modifies single Prototype that all instances share
    Me.prototype.window = window.outerWidth;
  });
}

Me.prototype.window = {};
```

Now, I don't fully endorse this as a good solution, but from all the constraints the OP kept adding after each suggestion, this seemed to be a last resort. But, again was rejected.

Comment: I need to initialize this stuff only if at least an instance is created, logically...

Comment: Why? The Prototype object of the constructor function will exist, whether instances of Me have been made or not. This will set the property on the Prototype object for the constructor function. When and If an instance is made, it will already have the correct property value and if the window is resized after any instances are made, the property will be updated for all of them. This is the point of Prototype.

Comment: It's only one event listener being attached to one object - -no matter how many Me instances you wind up with.

Comment: With your answer you are completely making useless all the classes, constructors and stuff like that logic. There's not isolation, you are adding a lot of code for nothing and the solution is not robust.

Comment: The robust solution was the fist one I suggested. You don't accept that, so you have no other choice but to know if there are any instances before registering a callback. Don't blame me for your application constraints. All I've done here is add one variable and one `if` statement. This has not made any types "useless". You are mistaking JavaScript for a class based language,when it is not -  it is a prototypical language.

Comment: So, I'm the one asking the question, by the way [here](https://gist.github.com/FezVrasta/7dd09d540408f777f158) you find a much more robust and clean solution to my problem.

Just to show you how the things should be done.

Comment: And, no. Your last edit is exactly like the example in my question. And it doesn't work as you describe.

Comment: You realize that the solution you posted is nothing more than a more complex version of my boolean variable to track if instances were made, right?

Comment: @FezVrasta: You are pretty harsh to someone who is trying to help *you*. Also, your "robust" solution seems to be based on information we didn't have. E.g. we didn't know that you want to remove the event handler if all instances are "destroyed" (or even the fact that your code deallocates instances explicitly). You can't expect us to come up with the "perfect" solution if we don't have all the relevant information.

Comment: Do you realize that if you had just posted your code and a full description of your requirements at the outset, instead of insulting me for trying to help you with insufficient information, we'd have avoided all this?

Comment: Well, you are the only one that seems to feel that way. Did you explain your full requirements in your question? No. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Adding here the solution I've used in the final code.
I've added a `destroy` method for completeness:

```
function Me() {
  this.init();
}

Me.prototype.window = 0;

// function used to update this.window
Me.prototype.onResizeBound = null;
Me.prototype.onResize = function() {
  Me.prototype.window = window.outerWidth;
};

// if there are no instances of Me, initialize the event listener
// then, add this instance to the instances list
Me.prototype.init = function() {
  if (this.instances === 0) {
    Me.prototype.onResizeBound = this.onResize.bind(this);
    window.addEventListener('resize', Me.prototype.onResizeBound);
  }
  this.instances++;
};

// remove this instance to the instances list
// if there are no more instances in the list, remove the event listener
Me.prototype.destroy = function() {
  this.instances--;

  if (this.instances === 0) {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', Me.prototype.onResizeBound);
  }
};
Me.prototype.instances = 0;
```

Example:

```
var a = new Me(); // added event listener
var b = new Me(); // not added event listener since one is already set
b.destroy(); // not removed event listener since one instance is still there
a.destroy(); // removed event listener since there are not other instances
```

Comment: So your solution is to have the prototype store an array (that could grow uncontrollably) and upon object construction, conditionally wire up an event handler based on a property of that array in a shared method of the prototype?  And you believe that is less complex and more robust than wiring up one event handler to one object (which requires no more resources than making an object method) and using just 3 lines of code to do it? OK. Good luck with your project.

Comment: be sure that if the array becomes to large to cause problems, the browser will have already biggest problems to handle.

Comment: You said my first (3 line) solution was no good because it used one event handler on one object, and that was not as good as zero event handlers, so clearly you are concerned with performance, but you seem to not have a problem carrying around an array of possibly many objects, when a single Boolean flag will do. Yeah, OK. Whatever.

Comment: Actually with this method I can completely add and remove the event listener automatically, and an array is nothing for a JS engine, which is optimized to store arrays. By the way I've improved it.

Comment: So now storing an array with potentially many elements is not a concern, but binding one object to one event handler is?  Oh, and if you want to be able to unbind, I can give you just 3 more lines that do the trick. Same result as your code MUCH less overhead and MUCH simpler, which I thought was what you were after. Guess not.

Comment: The problem is the access to the DOM, it's a concern when the app heavily depends on JS.

Comment: Why is one event handler a concern? Seems like even now, we're getting more information that should have been in the original question.

Comment: Everything that accesses the DOM is a concern for the performance of the applications written in JS